# How to implement Stylus Hover Pointer in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, stylus-pen

I am very new to AOSP and I want to implement Stylus Hover Pointer Code like it is in Samsung S-Pen.

I did explore on the native code and was not able to make any progress as most of the code was related to touches. How can I incorporate the HOVER actions with mimum latency. Guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, you will have to understand that adding a new input device would involve working on adding hardware support so that would include modifying the  kernel - adding a custom driver for the stylus, maybe a custom HAL and then exposing the APIs to the above layer. This would not be a very straightforward  activity.

Maybe you should consider the closest it would be to add support for a Bluetooth HID mouse? How does this stylus connect to your phone?

Comment: Hi, I have the HAL and custom apis exposed which indeed is getting some stylus events in the framework layer. Wanted to understand on how i can use some hover events to draw a small circle on the screen whenever the setting is on

Comment: If you can register it as an input device and override touch events onto a view? Getting out of ideas atm!

Comment: You can experiment with touch events with pressure set to 0.0.

Comment: Can I use AInputEvent in TouchInputMapper.cpp ? if so , how ? I have been trying to modify the show taps code to read the hover event and draw a pointer